# Spring integration - log each message with mdc to able to aggregate the messages

Tags: spring-integration, log4j2, spring-integration-dsl, mdc

I am using SpringIntegration's IntegrationFlows to define the message flow, and used Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter to get the message from the MQ, now I need to parse it, send it to KAFKA and update couchbase.

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.acarsMqListener))  //MQ Listener with session transacted=true
                .wireTap(ACARS_WIRE_TAP_CHNL)                                 // Logging the message
                .transform(agmTransformer, "parseXMLMessage")                                 .filter(acarsFilter,"filterMessageOnSmiImi")                  // Filter the message based on condition
                .handle(acarsProcessor, "processEvent")                       // Create the message
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(MESSAGE_KEY).topic(acarsKafkaTopic))  //send it to kafka
                .handle(updateCouchbase, "saveToDB")                          // Update couchbase
                .get();
```

For each message received we want to log it using MDC to help us to collect/aggregate it based on UUID.
Please suggest how to put the UUID in MDC and then clear out the MDC for each message in the above flow

Answer (score 0):

You just can configure a *global* `WireTap` and do an appropriate transformation over there in that wire-tapped flow before logging the message.

On the other hand there might be just need to play with MDC since you can inject something like `For` header into the message and `log()` them as usual, so you will see messages in logs and would be able to correlate using that header.